# Excel UDF Array Formula returning 0

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have an array formula as follows:

```
Public Function fafsa(inputRange As range, desks As range) As Integer

    Dim vArr() As Integer
    Dim i As Long

    ReDim vArr(1 To inputRange.Cells.Count, 1 To 1)

    i = 1   
    For i = 1 To inputRange.Cells.Count
        vArr(i, 1) = 1
    Next
    fasfa = vArr

End Function
```

When calling this from excel, as an array formula(Ctrl+Shift+Enter) it simply shows 0, whereas when I look at the array in the watch window, it is filled with 1s. Anyone have any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: You mistyped the name of your UDF in the last row. Use option explicit at the beginning of your code to prevent these kind of errors.

Comment: You are trying to return  `fafsa` as `Integer`, while inside your function you are trying to assign the entire `vArr` array to it. Since you are not also sharing what your **UDF** is suppose to do, it's hard for us to suggest the better solution for you.

Answer (score 1):

- As pointed out by @luuklag, you have a simple typo.

For some reason, VBA defaults to **NOT** requiring variable declarations.  You should change this by navigating to the General Tab of the Options window (tools --> options) and setting that option.  This will place `Option Explicit` at the start of every module, and you can examine `HELP` for its significance.

[image]

- Once you do that, you will get a type mis-match error.  This is because, unless your output type is Variant, you need to declare the output specifically as being an array.  So your first line should read:

---

```
Public Function fafsa(inputRange As Range, desks As Range) As Integer()
```

or

```
Public Function fafsa(inputRange As Range, desks As Range) As Variant
```

or

```
Public Function fafsa(inputRange As Range, desks As Range)
```

Comment: It's not just the typo, he is trying to assign the entire array to a type integer, so wither change the type he return from the function, or inside the Function.

Comment: @ShaiRado I addressed that issue.  And with the change in the first line, as well as correction of the typo, the function returns an array.

Comment: Now I see (you put it in the little print below). Also, not so sure why the PO wants this UDF if he is sending a single column range, there are easier ways to do it.

Comment: @ShaiRado I agree.  But my guess he is in learning mode, and that this either reflects that, and/or is part of a bigger project.